# List - Encapsulation & Performance - trade-off

Tags: c, performance, list, linked-list, encapsulation

Below is the code that implements `List` abstraction using both array and circular doubly linked list

```
/* list .h */
/*
   List is an ordered collection of homogenuous type elements(unique or duplicate).
   List is not designed to have collection of heterogenuous type elements
   All elements in a List are related.
   List is mutable
   Each element has a position.
   If an element is deleted, then still the remaining elements sit in new order.

   Array implementation of List
*/

#include<stddef.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>


typedef enum{false, true}bool;

typedef enum {CREATE_NEW_LIST, DOUBLE_THE_LIST, HALF_THE_LIST}Op;






#if defined(ARRAY)

  typedef struct List{

    int *array;
    int lastItemPosition;
    int size;
  }List;

  #define INITIAL_LIST_SIZE 50


#elif defined(LINKED_LIST)


  typedef struct DListNode{

    int item;
    struct DListNode *next;
    struct DListNode *prev;
  }DListNode;
  /*
    Reason to introduce 'List' type:

    Problem 1:
     Say, user code has 'x' and 'y' pointing to the same list that is built using 'Node' type.
     Some part of user code update list with new item using 'x'
     'y' is not in sync with this updation
        Node *x = someCreatedList;
        Node *y = x;
        Node *z = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        z->next = x;
        x = z; //y misses that reference.
    Solution:
     Maintain a List type, whose job is to point to head(first node) of the list.
     User code will go via reference of List type


    Problem 2:
     It make sense to have references of 'Node' type pointing to NULL
     Applying operation[insertItem()] on NULL pointer will cause runtime errors
    Solution:
     Run operations over List type because it does not make sense to have reference of SList type pointing to NULL.

    To solve problem1 & problem2, here is 'List' type
  */
  typedef struct List{ //Circular

    DListNode *head;
    int size; //size attribute is not part of list definition, but quick way to help user code
  }List;

  #define SENTINEL_ITEM -1


#else
  #error "Wrong list implementation macro name !!!"
#endif


void insertItem(List *, int, int);
void deleteItem(List *, int);
List* createList(List *, Op);
```

---

```
/* linkedListImpl.c */

#if defined(LINKED_LIST)

#include"list.h"


DListNode* createNode(int value){

  DListNode *newNode= malloc(sizeof(DListNode));

  newNode->next = newNode;
  newNode->prev = newNode;
  newNode->item = value;

  return newNode;
}


List *createList(List *list, Op opType ){

  List *lptr = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));

  if(opType == CREATE_NEW_LIST){

    /*
      Amidst performing operations on 'List', you need to check special cases
      for List with no item

      To reduce the number of special cases, we designate one node as 'SENTINEL'

      After using sentinel, there will be no NULL assignments/check in code.
    */

    DListNode *sentinel = createNode(SENTINEL_ITEM);


    lptr->head = sentinel;
    lptr->size = 0;

    return lptr;
  }else{

    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid flag passed to createList() \n");
    return (List *)NULL;
  }


}
void insertItem(List *linkedList, int newItem, int index){ //O(n)

  DListNode *positionElem = linkedList->head;
  bool isFirstElement = true; //assume

  if(index + 1 <= linkedList->size){

    fprintf(stderr, "Position already filled \n");
    return;
  }else{

    DListNode *newNode = createNode(newItem);


    while(index--){
      positionElem = positionElem->next;
      isFirstElement = false;
    }

    if(isFirstElement){

      newNode->next = positionElem;
      positionElem->prev = newNode;
    }else{

      newNode->next = positionElem->next;
      newNode->next->prev = positionElem->next;
    }
    newNode->prev = positionElem;
    positionElem->next = newNode;
  }

  return;
}


void deleteItem(List *linkedList, int index){

  //delete element  given index
  return;
}


#endif
```

---

```
/* arrayImpl.c */
#if defined(ARRAY)

#include"list.h"

List *createList(List *list, Op opType){

  List *lptr = (List *)malloc(sizeof(List));

  if(opType == CREATE_NEW_LIST){

    lptr->array = malloc(INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(int));
    lptr->array = memset(lptr->array, -1, INITIAL_LIST_SIZE*sizeof(int));
    lptr->lastItemPosition = -1;
    lptr->size = INITIAL_LIST_SIZE;
  }else if(opType == DOUBLE_THE_LIST){

    lptr->array = malloc(2*(list->size)*sizeof(int));
    lptr->array = memcpy(lptr->array, list->array, list->size*sizeof(int));
    lptr->lastItemPosition = list->lastItemPosition;;
    lptr->size = 2*(list->size);
  }else if(opType == HALF_THE_LIST){

    lptr->array = malloc(((list->size)/2)*sizeof(int));
    lptr->array = memcpy(lptr->array, list->array, (list->size/2)*sizeof(int));
    lptr->lastItemPosition = list->lastItemPosition;;
    lptr->size = (list->size)/2;
  }

  return lptr;

}

void insertItem(List *arrayList, int newItem, int index){

  /* House keeping */
  if(arrayList->lastItemPosition + 1 == arrayList->size){
    arrayList = createList(arrayList, DOUBLE_THE_LIST);
  }


  /* Insert the element */
  arrayList->array[index] = newItem;
  if(index > arrayList->lastItemPosition){
     arrayList->lastItemPosition = index;
  }

  return;
}

void deleteItem(List *arrayList, int index){

  arrayList->array[index] = -1;
  if(index == arrayList->lastItemPosition){
    arrayList->lastItemPosition--;
  }

  /* House keeping */
  if(arrayList->size > INITIAL_LIST_SIZE){
    if(arrayList->lastItemPosition == ((arrayList->size)/2)){
      arrayList = createList(arrayList, HALF_THE_LIST);
    }
  }


}


#endif
```

---

```
/* main.c */
#include"list.h"

int main(void){
  List *linkedList = (List *)NULL;
  linkedList = createList((List *)NULL, CREATE_NEW_LIST);
  //List *arrayList = createList(CREATE_NEW_LIST);


  if (linkedList == (List *)NULL){
    fprintf(stderr, "Unable to createList() \n");
    exit(1); //Nothing else to do without linkedList
  }

  insertItem(linkedList, 1, 0);
}
```

---

Compiled as

```
> gcc -DLINKED_LIST main.c arrayImpl.c linkedListImpl.c
```

---

> ***Encapsulation*** is about maintaining invariants of an ADT `List`
>
> > The following invariants apply to the `List` with a `sentinel`.
> >
> > (1) For any `List d`, `d.head != NULL`. (There’s always a sentinel.)
> >
> > (2) For any `DListNode x`, `x.next != NULL`.
> >
> > (3) For any `DListNode x`, `x.prev != NULL`.
> >
> > (4) For any `DListNode x`, if `x.next == y`, then `y.prev == x`.
> >
> > (5) For any `DListNode x`, if `x.prev == y`, then `y.next == x`.
> >
> > (6) A `List`’s `size` member is the number of `DListNode`'s, NOT COUNTING the `sentinel` (pointed by "head"), that can be accessed from the `sentinel` by a sequence of `next references.
>
> ***Abstraction*** is the creation of barrier between representation and usage(user interface)

---

Question:

`O(1)` insertion and deletion is possible by providing `DListNode` node access via `insertItem()`/`deleteItem()` user interfacece to user(`main.c`). But, Encapsulation will be broken due to malfunction by user on that `DListNode` type node. How to enforce `O(1)` using linked list?

Comment: If you consider user error to break encapsulation, C is not the right language for you.

Comment: @EOF Using C syntax, Can author provide node to user that user unable to modify but read ?

Comment: You could make the data structures you pass around `const`, but the code that uses these data structures can *always* cast away the `const`ness and modify the data. This may result in undefined behavior and it will be the fault of whoever cast away the `const`, but as I said: If you consider user error as breaking encapsulation, C is not the right language for you.

Comment: You might want to look at C++ which has the features to separate public and private interfaces to a struct/class.

Comment: @BoPersson Cant I do that in C?  Like Linux kernel is object oriented C. So how we ensure public/private using C?

Comment: @overexchange Linux Kernel isn't object-orientated C. C isn't object-orientated.

Comment: @user997112 Do you think this is OOP code written in C? https://github.com/shamhub/Computing/tree/master/design2Code/list